# Removing skew from ordinal variables

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, ordinal-data, skewness, categorical-encoding

I'm working on the [ames housing data set](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) and wondering how to deal with some string-valued variables.

The variable `LandSlope` can take the values `Sev` for "severe", `Mod` for "moderate" and `Gtl` for "gentle. This indicates that it is actually an ordinal value and [we should use label encoding to retain this ordinality](https://www.kaggle.com/serigne/stacked-regressions-top-4-on-leaderboard#231486), rather than using One-Hot-Encoding.

I apply the label encoding

```
data['LandSlope']=data['LandSlope'].replace(['Sev', 'Mod', 'Gtl'], [2, 1, 0])
```

Now I have a new numerical variable that takes on values from the set `{2, 1, 0}`. Analysing the distribution of this variable I find there is significant right-skewness:

[image]

By transforming the variable with the [Box-Cox transformation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) I could bring reduce the skewness from from `4.9733` to `4.2117`. ( As depicted above).

However looking at the quantile plot, I'm wondering if this is actually advised. Is it recommended to reduce the skewness of variables after applying LabelEncoding?

Comment: The distribution of predictor variables does not matter. Your re-coding does suppose that the difference between severe and moderate is equal to the difference between moderate and gentle.

Comment: It's amazing what ML practitioners *don't* know about scaling metrics such as categorically and ordinally scaled features. First of all, your graphs are scatterplots that would be much more meaningfully represented as bar charts. Next, this link (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/webbooks/reg/chapter5/regression-with-saschapter-5-additional-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regressionanalysis/) describes many approaches to categorical info. For your purposes, effect coding would be best, e.g., (Sev=1, Mod=0, Gtl=-1).

Comment: DJohnson thanks for the reference. @mdewey can you please back up your claim? I have heard contrary statements: https://www.kaggle.com/serigne/stacked-regressions-top-4-on-leaderboard#231486 Transformation of highly skewed features.

Comment: @DJohnson, could you add *why* it would be best represented as effect coding? I tried an honest google search and can't find something decisive.

Comment: If you think the skew of predictors matter ML people would not use what they call one-hot encoding either since that usually leads to a number of 0/1 variables which are all skewed. I cannot see anything in the discussion you link to which states why skew matters.

Comment: The part where the author applies the boxcox transformation to all numerical predictors. I cannot provide a deep link. Please CTRL+F for Box Cox Transformation of (highly) skewed features

Comment: See the section on 'Effect Coding' in this Wiki article ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable

Comment: The quantile plots shown and equivalent bar charts (should) show precisely the same information. I can't see any meaning to Box-Cox here, as it entails a recoding from three grades (conventionally successive integers) to three other grades (presumably unequally spaced), all for the sake of greater symmetry which is elusive if only because, and not only because, the gentle category is modal whatever you do to it. But whatever you did seems to  have mapped three values to two, which can make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I am not perturbed by skewness in an ordinal predictor, which would appear in models only as a set of indicators any way.

Comment: For "would" read "should", as there is no accounting for what people might do. All under the heading "in my opinion".

Comment: To echo @NickCox, note that since one typically allows oneself the flexibility of recentering and rescaling variables (which are merely changes in their unit of measurement), including a Box-Cox transformation gives you the freedom to apply literally any strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function to the original numerical codes.  In other words, pick any three numbers you like and assign them to your categories to preserve their order. The statistical question concerns what that accomplishes for your model and, if it accomplishes anything, how best to select those three numbers.

Comment: ordinal scale is categorical, and hardly support the notion of "skewness". Unbalancedness woulld be a better word. Box-Cox transform is for continuous data.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments, a short summary:

You have an ordinal predictor variable, and how to represent it in part depends on how you will use it. If you just use it as an numerical variable in a linear regression, using values like $1,2,3$ (or $-1,0,1$), you are assuming that the difference (in effect on the target variable) that `Mod` is halfway between `Gtl` and `Sev`. But if you model with a monotone spline (or even with a quadratic term) such an assumption is avoided.

But all of this has little to do with skewness, and the use of a Box-Cox transform is difficult to understand. For more detail and opinion see all the excellent comments.